# Minimum Server configuration for 10 nodes(client)

Tags: hardware-acceleration

Could you please give idea for server configuration of 10 nodes for small size Hospital. Following information is needed. 1)Processor 2)RAM 3)corresponding mother board 4)Cabinet 5)OS (that suitable for small Hospital)

Ready-made server available in market is costly for me. PLease help.

Comment: Have you tried eBay ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). You could try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).